# Two packages which contain modules with same name

Tags: python, python-2.7, package, setuptools

Let's say we have two python packages.

First one called `lib1` and contains `sample` module.

In `setup.py` our name is `name='lib1'`.

So after installing, we could just use it as `import sample`.

But what if `lib2` contains module `sample`?

Seems there will be a conflict.

How to deal with it? Is there any agreements?

```
lib1
    sample
    tests
    setup.py


lib2
    sample
    tests
    setup.py
```

Answer (score 1):

Just define an alias for the module in each package when importing...

something like:

```
import package1.module as uniquemod1
import package2.module as uniquemod2
```

Comment: If I'm trying to import it as `import lib1.sample` that gives me error `ImportError: No module named lib1.sample`

Comment: what is the full path from you project root to your package/module? if it's within another package, make sure to state it as well etc...

Answer (score 0):

Use alias or be very deliberate with your references to those libraries

```
import package1
import package2

# There should be no mistaking which function is being called this way
package1.module.function()
package2.module.function()
```